# Underscores don't show up in some colorschemes

Tags: colorscheme, filetype-tex

Sometimes, when I'm using the torte colorscheme and editing latex files, my latex expressions inside of `$` signs show up in yellow. When this happens, my underscores disappear, as the following figure illustrates (what's written here is actually `$a_1$`):

[image: Example figure]

For other latex files (I haven't yet figured out what makes the difference) the same expression would show up in a different color and the underscore would be visible: so there's something wierd going on with yellow. All my other symbols show up fine.

Is there any way to fix this, so that I can see the underscores, even in yellow? Thanks!

Comment: could something be with the filetyp detection, have you tried running  :set ft? on the incorrect, and a correct file and confirm that it is the same ?

Comment: For some reason, today I can't replicate the problem!!   (In fact, it was only yesterday that the problem showed up.)   I will try this next time I have the problem again.

Comment: You can reproduce by opening an empty buffer in Vim, then do: `set ft=plaintex` and write `$a_1$`.

Comment: That does enable me to replicate the problem, unfortunately `set ft=latex` doesn't  fix it.    Nor does `g:tex_flavor = 'latex'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the filetype is set to `plaintex` instead of `tex`. You can "force" Vim to always use the `tex` filetype with:

```
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

See `:h g:tex_flavor` for more info.